# React client authentication with ASP.NET MVC Simple Membership

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, authentication, model-view-controller

We have an old site built with MVC. We are now going to convert this site into a React front-end, and a .Net Core back-end. We are attempting to convert bit by bit. This means during the conversion period we will have a site mixed with MVC Views, and React.

My dilemma is that I need to authenticate the React client with the ASP.NET MVC Simple Membership in order to consume the MVC APIs. I have tried created a React login form that submits to the LoginController, and that request responds with success, however when calling another API with [Authorize] the React client is rejected.

My Question summed up is; Is it even possible to Authenticate a React client with ASP.NET MVC Simple Membership?

If so, how would you go about doing it? And are there any articles written on doing this?

Response from LoginController:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "success": true,
    "changePassword": false
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "cache-control": "private"
  },
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "http://localhost:49632/api/Login?email=john.doe@gmail.com&password=password1"
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

Comment: What do you get back from the form when it is successfully submitted? A token you must use in upcoming requests?

Comment: @Tholle, I edited the question to include the response from the login.

Comment: Great. Can you see if the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie is set in the browser?

Comment: I don't see anything by that name in the console under Application/Storage/Cookies. Should I?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, since you only get `"success": true` in the request response, I would think a cookie is set instead. What request library are you using? fetch? axios?

Comment: We are using axios to make requests.